# Pronunciation of foreign IT abbreviations / languages

Tags: информатика, фонетика

I am studying CS in the Czech Republic and recently have noticed that when I talk to Russian programmers, I tend to mispronounce widely known words (famous site names,abbreviations, language names). 
So I would be grateful to anyone who could provide me with a relatively long list of phonetical conventions in Russian IT diaspora.

Examples:

- https://github.com - **[г'итхуп]** or **[г'ифап]**?
- PHP - **[пэхапэ]** or **[п'иэй'ч'п'и]**?
- Java - **[джава]** or **[й'ава]**?
- C  - **[c'и]** or **[цэ]**?
- Bash - **[бэш]**  or **[баш]**
- VHDL  - **[вэхадээл]** or  **[в'иэй'ч'д'иэл']**

etc.

Comment: I like your question)

Comment: Thanks, I was just confused cause I study in another language with other conventions. We e.g. say [бэш].

Comment: These is no consensus on some terms (like `SQL` or `Linux`) even among English speakers :)

Comment: Just as a sidenote: there is no English word "informatics", it's called IT (information technology).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of listing all possible variations of any which abbreviation, here is the summary of the usage of such terms:

- Most technical abbreviations can be understood if either phonetically copied from their English reading (*e.g.*, for HTML it would be *эйч-ти-эм-эл*), transliterated into respective Russian letters (*e.g. ха-тэ-эм-эл*, with variations such as *ха* / *хэ*, *эм* / *мэ* and so forth), or voiced in Latin letter names (*аш-тэ-эм-эль*) just as customary in sciences, like chemistry.
- For brand names, again, either phonetic calque (*Джава* for Java, *Майкрософт* for Microsoft, *Эпл* for Apple, or, with slight modifications, such as *пайтон* for Python), Russian equivalent for words (*Питон*, *Яблоко*), or phonetic transliteration (*Микрософт*, *Нове́лл*, *Борланд*).
- Some brand names or abbreviations may have slang versions, such as *Мелкомягк(ое, ие…)* for Microsoft (a bit disdainful), *жаба* for Java, *аська* for ICQ, *ирка* for IRC, or *мускул* for MySQL (humorous, near-consonance), or *красная шапочка* for Red Hat Linux. Or neverending associations of Fedora Linux with the phrase “*дело в шляпе*”.
- WWW sometimes referred to as *цэ-цэ-цэ* or *три цэ* because it is a simple mistake one can make when forgetting to switch keyboard layout. Standard QWERTY layout corresponds to standard Russian ЙЦУКЕН, and there when one tries to use <kbd>W</kbd> key, the letter *Ц* appears.
- CMS, as “Content Management System” sometimes translated to “*Система управления контентом (содержанием)*”, and thus abbreviated as *СУКа*, and declined accordingly. It is done in a humorous way, precisely for [the reasons](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC#cite_note-1) that Wikipedia article mentions. It may not be very common, but I had seen, and adopted it from some known site or author in RuNet (possibly, via [Spectator](http://spectator.ru/entry/821)).

Comment: There are too many cases of colloquial usage where a speaker which uses special jargon tries to demonstrate his personal closeness to a phenomenon using a misstyled name. One of the most weird variant I saw is "АО Межделмаш" for IBM. Also, "Бимеры" for the same firm. "Осёл" for Internet Explorer (because "И-а!") It's impossible to deduce these substantivates without some extra mental work or context:) Fedora Core - "Федорино горе". Most of such names are pejorative in some aspect and, of course, strictly prohibited in official materials.

Comment: @Netch o__O Межделмаш???? Круто.

Answer (score 6):

Unreal. I believe 90% of Ru IT community will be glad *to know* how to spell those words correctly and if they do spell good enough now. There are too many unofficial variants to cover.
More examples:

- www: [3цэ], [вэ-вэ-вэ], [цэ-цэ-цэ], [дабл'ю-дабл'ю-дабл'ю];
- Mysql: [май-эс-кью-эл], [май-сиквел], [мускул], [мускуль], [мАйсикл];

All those are ~correct and depend only on local rules. Usually you can't be sure will you match or not even if you use well known spelling.

Comment: Where are these data? [вэ-вэ-вэ], [дабл'ю-дабл'ю-дабл'ю], [три дабл'ю], [май-эс-кью-эл], - it's true. I have never heard your other words at my work.

Comment: Now you know :)

Comment: OMG, how is ccc related to www? can't they distinguish letters? o_0

Comment: ccc (and others) is in Ukraine, I think

Comment: That's en/ru (w/ц) letter in Russian layout and when you start to print with incorrect one it comes as [ццц].

Comment: Shame on me, I have to recall Russian alphabet letter position! Layout fault.

Comment: "мускул" is really funny :):):) It reminds me of an old joke about Windows converting "My Documents" to 8+3 notation as "MyDocu~1", and someone commenting that "Мудаки" is spelled with an "a", not an "o".

Comment: ну хоть слово "аська" знаю. уже хорошо =)

Answer (score 3):

- github.com - [гит'хап]
- PHP - [пэхэпэ] and also [пи эйч пи]
- Java - [джава]
- C - [c'и]
- Bash - [б'аш]
- VHDL - [в'иэй'ч'д'иэл']
- HTML - [хэ тэ мэ эл'] and also [эйч ти эм эл']
- CSS - [цэ эс эс] and also  [си эс эс]
- CMS - [цэ мэ эс] and also [си эм эс]
- Python - [пи'тон]
- IT - [и тэ] and also [ай ти]

All these terms are colloquial.

Comment: Those who know history of Python also use [пайтон], IT sometime called [ит] referring to "it" (оно).

Comment: I agree with [пайтон], but [ит] is also strange for me)))

Comment: @CleverMasha : there is an online magazine containing stories that happened in admins' or programmers' life - IT happens. Here it is a wordplay and is pronounced  [ит] .

Comment: Making parallel with "it" people show that something goes wrong with IT staff/department. IT happens also one of the source.

Comment: OK, @revoua, got the hint.

Comment: It's interesting)

Comment: Bash is usually pronounced as [баш]. Github is not abbrevation, but two words combined. It is usually transliterated as гитхаб  [г'итхаб]

Comment: ИТ, кстати, вполне себе кошерная аббревиатура фразы «информационные технологии».

Answer (score 3):

To add a slightly different point of view to many nice answers and comments here: Probably, there is no correct answer to this question, and it is not specific to Russian only. For example, the American abbreviation SPIE is pronounced both as S-P-I-E and as [spai] by native speakers.

In Russian, not only the traditions but also the knowledge of foreign languages define how a person will pronounce a particular word. My IT professor in university tended to pronounce FALSE as [фальш], the reason being her bad knowledge of English and a logical use of the corresponding German word.

Accordingly, pronunciation such as [пэ-ха-пэ] for PHP come from Latin, since in Russian schools Latin letter names are used: [цэ] for *c*, [икс] for *x*, [ха] for *h* etc.

That said, I have noticed that those with good knowledge of English tend to pronounce the abbreviations, mostly coming from English, in the proper English way: using [дабл-ю] for *w*, [эйч] for *h* etc. Simply because they use the same conventions when e.g. spelling words in English.

Of course, traditions play an important role here. While the language name С will be in most cases pronounced as [си], it will also often be declined: `писать на сях`.

Finally, some IT terms have equivalents in Russian; in these rare cases Russian words are often used: [ада] for *Ada*, [опал] for *Opal*, [питон] for *Python* etc.

Comment: Why not close the question then, if it is not specific to RL&U ? Or maybe I'd better rewrite it (answers showed me that it can be developed into a more interesting one).

Comment: It is quite specific to RLU in my opinion. It's just that a similar situation sometimes occurs in other languages too.

Comment: OK then =) leave my question, however, I will still modify it. There are two answers here that seem the best to me, one is yours. I'll probably rely on voting now, cause I like both of those answers and wish I could accept two... So prepare to compete =)

Comment: It's the second time discussion with you makes me ask a new question. Isn't this great? =)

Comment: @Umari, I am pleased :)

Answer (score 2):

I want to extend Masha's answer with what I use/see:

- github - [жит'хап]
- PHP - [по-ха-пэ]
- Java - [жава], [ява], [жаба]
- C++ - [си плюс плюс], [си пэ пэ]
- MySQL - [май-эс-ку-эль]
- DHCP - [дэ-хэ-цэ-пэ], [ди-аш-си-пи]
- DNS - [дэ-эн-эс]

Some of these terms are colloquial, some of them are humorous and some are correct (i.e. follow [rules of transcription](http://ru.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=%D0%90%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%BE-%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) )

And @revoua is right: you can't be sure will you match or not even if you use well known spelling because it depends only on local rules.

Comment: С++ is very often [плюсы́]

Comment: "Жит" for "git" is definite error. C++ is sometimes named "кресты" (mainly pejorative).